# Why some functions are uppercased and some lowercased

Tags: postgresql

Though PostgreSQL is case-insensitive, in the documentation some functions names shown uppercased and others lowercased. For example `COALESCE(...)`, `NULLIF(...)`, `length(...)`, `AGG(...)`, `string_agg(...)`.

What's the reason for it?

Comment: Different authors I guess. Or maybe functions that are part of the SQL standard are written in upper case, Postgres specific are written in lower case

Answer (score -1):

Postgres is case insensitive. You can any of the function either in lower case or in upper case.

COALESCE(...) and coalesce(...) is same. Both gives the same result.

In documentation its just a format.

Comment: Please, reread the question I've already said that PostgreSQL is case-insensitive.